# Appending a copy of a divs contents without doubling

Tags: jquery

I want to add another copy of a div or just it's contents below the original. Using .clone() it will double every time. I want to add one more of the same every time. Can't figure it out. Any suggestions. Code is currently.

```
$("#element").click(function(){

    var newElement = $("#element").clone();
    $("#element").append(newElement);

});
```

Comment: can you share the html as well

Comment: since you are cloning an element with id it will create multiple elements with same id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g9xXJ/1/)**

Try this code...

```
 $("#element").click(function(){
    var newElement =$('<div/>').html($("#element").html());
    $("#element").after(newElement);
});
```

Comment: Couldn't get it working. My div contains input fields if that effects it?

Comment: If you go with creating a new empty <div/> for a clone, then make sure you add in any style or class attributes to it from the original div if any.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the element empty() and then `append`.

```
$("#element").click(function(){   
    var newElement = $("#element").clone();
    $("#element").empty();
    $("#element").append(newElement);

});
```

[**Difference here With Empty() and without Empty()**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshbm13/fRUUd/1512/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. In your jsfiddle clicking on withempty doesn't add any copies. Whilst the without empty copies exponentially.

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want it to double, use

```
$("#element").html(newElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/73Hb4/1/

Not the cleanest solution, but get's it done.

Basically you clone the set before the first add action, and then re-use it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var elements;
    $("#someid").on('click', function(){
        if(!elements)
        elements = $("#someid").clone();

        $("#someid").append(elements.clone());
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will append copy of element just after current element

```
$("#element").click(function () {
    $(this).after($(this).html());
});
```

Comment: if you inspect the DOM after that, you'll see that the div does not get duplicated but only the inner contents of the div (which of course is fine as he's mentioned that even the contents will do)

Answer (score 0):

The reason its cloning every time is because [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) includes the content *within* the div. So you're not getting a cloned div but cloned content within the same div, hence it doubles.

What you really need is [after](http://api.jquery.com/after/). You can verify this with an alert(newElement.html()) after the clone*.

So to actually clone a div after the current div, you'd also need the entire div itself, so apart from some answers already provided, we could use the outerHTML property.

```
$("#element").click(function(){

    var newElement = $(this.outerHTML);
    $("#element:last").after(newElement);

});
```

If you need the click handler to work on any of the new divs as well, you'd need the equivalent of deprecated [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

```
$(document).on('click', '#element', function()
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kAFb9/)
(Variation of Prabu's demo that includes the above. With multiple ids, I'd prefer to use a class instead of #id like in the demo)

- alternatives to alert: log.debug or firebug